# Trying to connect a mysql database to an excel sheet using visual basics

Tags: mysql, excel, vba

I feel like this is a simple problem but i cant seem to figure it out. I am trying to establish a connection between my excel sheet and my mysql server but keep getting the error "Run-time error '-2147467259 (80004005)':
[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified" I have the necessary drivers installed so i am unsure where to go from here, this is the code i have so far

```
Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim TableName As String
Dim sqlstr As String
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

Dim CRow As Long, Trow As Long
Dim Column1 As Integer, Column2 As Integer

Set conn = New ADODB.Connection

conn.Open ("DRIVER = {MySQL ODBC 5.3 Unicode Driver}" _
& ";SERVER=127.0.0.1" _
& ";DATABASE=tmi_stock" _
& ";UID=root" _
& ";PWD=MyRoot2018")

Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

sqlstr = "INSERT INTO tester VALUE(1, 2)"
rs.Open sqlstr, conn, adOpenStatic

Set rs = Nothing
conn.Close
Set conn = Nothing
```